# How do I tell Visual Studio to use MERGE_MSG as default commit message?

Tags: git, visual-studio

When performing a git merge with conflicts in Visual Studio it seems to ignore .git/MERGE_MSG ad just leaves me to manually insert a commit message which basically contains the same information (which branch was merged and a list of the conflicting files).
How can I tell Visual Studio to autofill the content of .git/MERGE_MSG into the commit message by default like Source Tree does for example?

Comment: Is there exist a file in `.git/MERGE_MSG`?

Comment: I have verified that `.git/MERGE_MSG` exists and is not empty.

Comment: It's still an open [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2019-auto-populate-git-merge-commit-me/586587) in VS